# Python pandas str.extract from multiple columns

Tags: python, regex, pandas, extract, multiple-columns

I'm trying to extract string pattern from multiple columns into a single result column using Pandas and str.extract.

My sample dataframe is as follows.

```
field1   field2
ab1234   ab1234
ac1234   
qw45     rt23
c1234b   cb1234
cv       1234dd
...
```

I want to extract the '1234' (EDIT: any 4 digits integer not just '1234') from either column (field1 and field2 in this case) into a new result column to have the desired result below

```
field1   field2   result
ab1234   ab1234   1234
ac1234            1234
qw45     rt23     
c1234b   cb1234   1234
cv       1234dd   1234
...
```

I'm attempting to use pandas str.extract to obtain my desired result, however, I have been unsuccessful as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re


df = pd.DataFrame({'field1':['ab1234','ac1234','qw45', 'c1234b', 'cv'], 
'field2':['ab1234','','rt23','cb1234', '1234dd']})

df['result'] = df[['field1', 'field2']].apply(lambda x: 
x.str.extract(r'(\d{4})', flags = re.IGNORECASE, expand = 
False)).any(axis=1)

print(df)
```

The above only returns Boolean results. I'm wondering if the above can be converted to return actual pattern or are there other ways of tackling this problem?

Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT: Sorry I should mention the pattern could be any 4 digits integer not just '1234'. Thus, I want the result column to return these 4 digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC

```
df['New']=df.apply(','.join,axis=1).str.extract(r'(\d{4})', expand = 
False).fillna('')
df
   field1  field2   New
0  ab1234  ab1234  1234
1  ac1234          1234
2    qw45    rt23      
3  c1234b  cb1234  1234
4      cv  1234dd  1234
```

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there, you can do the following.
We can use a `for loop` to apply `str.extract` twice to create two temporary columns.

After that create the final column `result` with `fillna`.

```
cols = ['field1', 'field2']
n=1
for col in cols:
    df['result'+str(n)] = df[col].str.extract('([0-9]{4})')
    n += 1

df['result'] = df.result1.fillna(df.result2).fillna('')
df.drop(['result1', 'result2'], inplace=True, axis=1)

print(df)
   field1  field2 result
0  ab1234  ab1234   1234
1  ac1234           1234
2    qw45    rt23       
3  c1234b  cb1234   1234
4      cv  1234dd   1234
```

Comment: Thanks very much Erfan, this works fine, never thought of using .fillna. Just wondering, if you would still recommend utilising .fillna for more complex conditions such as more than 2 fields to extract or applying multiple patterns? Thanks again Erfan.

Comment: @nqcthanh with regex you can extract multiple patterns, but that would require a more complex regex code. I would suggest to post another question for that.